# Outlook VBA - How to unzip content

Tags: vba, outlook, 7zip, compression

**Background:**
I have a script that iterates through emails (without any emails being selected) in an Outlook folder saving their attachments to the desktop.

**Issue:**
The attachment is a zip-file and I wonder if it is possible to save the decompressed file within (an .xls file) to the desktop instead?

Thank You!

Comment: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win002.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any method for that. You need to save the attached file on the disk and then unzip it programmatically.

If you try to use any search engine you can find the following links with a sample code:

- [VBA - Unzip files using VBA](http://ckannan.blogspot.com.by/2012/09/vba-unzip-files-using-vba.html)
- [Macro to Unzip Files - It's Just Creating Empty Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809056/macro-to-unzip-files-its-just-creating-empty-folders)
- [Unzip file(s) with the default Windows zip program (VBA)](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win002.htm)